# Unable to upload latest glue package 1.3.0

Tags: r, package, r-glue

I am doing a course in R and one of the codes they've asked us to run requires tidyr. I can install tidyr, but when I run the code I encounter: 'namespace 'glue' 1.2.0 is already loaded, but >=1.3.0 is required'. I have tried several ways to address this including:

- re-starting R with a new session and reinstalling glue (note I have the latest version of R)
- installing the glue package using the direct link from CRAN
- deleting the glue package directly from my library folder and reinstalling
- downloading the glue package 1.3.0 zip folder and extracting files to my library folder and then reinstalling.

Despite this, every time I install glue, I get version 1.2.0.

How can I upload the latest version of glue?

Comment: Could you share the output of SessionInfo() ?

Comment: Is glue 1.2.0 installed into one of your system libraries?

Comment: @MarcoSandri I am unable to upload the whole SessionInfo() as it is too long. However, 'glue_1.2.0' is under the heading 'other attached packages'.

Comment: @Dason when I install glue it is saved into 'win-library' within my Documents folder (apologies - I am a recent R user, hopefully that answers your question).

Comment: You can paste the output of SessionInfo() in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To see if the package truly needs updating, you can run:

```
old.packages()
```

This will list all packages where an update is available. If 'glue' is there, try:

```
update.packages()
```

Which will update all available packages previously listed.